# How does this calculation a -= a + a works? (int a = 1) The result of the execution is -1, not 1

Tags: java

```
int a = 1;

a -= a + a;
```

The above code result is -1, which I am expecting it to be 1.

But the below code actually get me 1

```
a = a - a + a
```

Aren't they supposed to be the same? How the first code get to -1?

I tried to look at mathematical order of operation of addition and subtraction, which I thought I would have misunderstanding on how they works. But it looks like I am correct by doing left to right operation on the calculation.

Comment: First `a + a` is calculated, that's 2. Then `a -= 2` is calculated, the result is -1. The actual calculation is not `a - a + a` but `a - (a + a)`, which is the same as `a - a - a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java Language Specification [writes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

That is, the expression

```
a -= a + a
```

is equivalent to

```
a = (int) ((a) - (a + a))
```

which evaluates like

```
a = (1) - (1 + 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

`-=` has lower precedence than `+`, so the order of operations is:

```
a -= (a + a);
a -= (1 + 1);
a -= 2;
```

On the other hand, `-` has the same precedence as `+`, and is left-associative, so the order of operations here is:

```
a = ((a - a) + a);
a = ((1 - 1) + 1);
a = (   0    + 1);
a = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense that the answer is -1 since a -= a+a means you are setting the variable a to the value of a-(a+a). Since a is initialized as 1, a-(a+a)=1-(1+1)=1-2=-1.

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations - in the first one, a + a is calculated then that is subtracted from a. In the second one, the subtraction of a from a is done, then the addition (left to right).